# Import nested array string as list in django / python

Tags: python, django

After some hours of searching I didn't find how to do the following (rather basic) operation in django:

In my dbase I have a string like [["Correct", "true"], ["Wrong", "false"], ["OK", "true"]]

I would like to convert it to a list so I can shuffle it using random.shuffle, concatenate it to other lists etc. Of course the sublists (pairs) should stay together.

In the end I would return it as a HTTP response to the webpage.

I used json.load, ast.litteral_eval but that didn't work.

ast.litteral_eval threw an indentation error in /usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py in parse, line 37

Code of views.py:

```
def request_block_data(request, block_number):
    obj1 = BlockData.objects.get(pk = 1)
    list1 = ast.literal_eval(obj1.block_data)

    obj2 = BlockData.objects.get(pk = 2)
    list2 = ast.literal_eval(obj2.block_data)

    if (True):
        output =  random.shuffle(list1 + list2) 

    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Any help appreciated!

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/block/request_block_data/1/

Django Version: 1.8.3
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'block',
 'amsterdam')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/baze/www/django/back/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/baze/www/django/back/amsterdam/block/views.py" in request_block_data
  16.     list1 = ast.literal_eval(obj1.block_data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py" in literal_eval
  49.         node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py" in parse
  37.     return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

Exception Type: IndentationError at /block/request_block_data/1/
Exception Value: unexpected indent (<unknown>, line 1)
```

Comment: "ast.litteral_eval but that didn't work". is there any error ?

Comment: Please specify what exactly "it didn't work" means, and indent your code correctly.  This will help people to help you. :)

Comment: Yes, strangely i get indentation error in /usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py in parse, line 37

Exception Type: IndentationError at /block/request_block_data/1/
Exception Value: unexpected indent (<unknown>, line 1)

Comment: Please edit the question to provide the full traceback

Comment: I think you do not have a proper valid python code snippet there.

Comment: ... *"the full traceback"*. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Also you're going to need to show the **exact** string. It looks like you have some indentation in it.

Comment: Yes, giving the result of `repr(obj2.block_data)` would probably be helpful.

Comment: Strangely the output of repr(obj2.block_data) is u'[["Juist", true], ["fout", false]]'

Comment: I dont know where this u' is coming from but i guess this is causing trouble in evaluating the string

Comment: `u'some_string'` just means that the string is Unicode. It shouldn't cause a problem in evaluating the string in any recent Python version, but it may in old versions of Python 3.

Comment: I'm using pyhon 2.7. For completeness: repr(obj1.block_data) gives u' [["GOED", "true"], ["JUIST", "true"], ["CORRECT", "true"], ["EXACT", "true"], ["IN ORDE", "true"], ["MIS", "false"], ["ONJUIST", "false"], ["INCORRECT", "false"], ["VERKEERD", "false"], ["FOUT", "false"]]'. So no indentation or special characters there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string `u'[["Juist", true], ["fout", false]]'` is not valid Python code - because lower-case `true` and `false` do not exist in Python - so `ast.literal_eval` would give a NameError, not an IndentationError.

However, that string is perfectly valid JSON, so `json.loads` would work fine.

**Update**

Block 1, which you should have posted originally, starts with a space. You'll need to strip that off first:

```
ast.literal_eval(block1.strip())
```

Or, as I said, use `json.loads()`.

Comment: OK thanks for pointing me to the trailing space! That caused trouble in ast.literal_eval.
json.loads didn't bother about it though.

Comment: I prefer now using ast.literal_eval because it does not add the annoying u for unicode. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to fix your indentation
Once that is fixed, you may have a shot at getting the lists combined

```
def request_block_data(request, block_number):
    obj1 = BlockData.objects.get(pk = 1)
    list1 = ast.literal_eval(obj1.block_data)

    obj2 = BlockData.objects.get(pk = 2)
        list2 = ast.literal_eval(obj2.block_data)


    if True:
        output =  random.shuffle(list1 + list2) 

    return HttpResponse(output)
```

One note: the conditional if is redundant, because `True` is always `True`.

You can write directly

```
output =  random.shuffle(list1 + list2)
```

Omitting it altogether.

Than post thee traceback or what you get back

Comment: sorry indentation got weird pasting code in SO. I edited the question and now it is as it is in my code.

Comment: as @jonrsharpe pointed out, report the `repr(obj2.block_data)` result and also the `repr(obj1.block_data)` and result so we have an idea.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval('[["Correct", "true"], ["Wrong","false"]]')` 
returns the list
`[['Correct', 'true'], ['Wrong', 'false']]`